# fastapi interactive plot update in template with highcharts

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, highcharts, jinja2, fastapi

I'm trying to plot some database array in a highcharts plot with fastapi jinja2 template engine.

This is how my `main.py` looks like:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import uvicorn
import random

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")


templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def dash(request: Request):
    data = [random.randint(0,40) for _ in range(12)] # this will be a database call
    # if there is a diff, update the graph, else do nothing
    return templates.TemplateResponse("dash.html", {"request": request, "title": "my random graph", "tokyo_data": data})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", port=80, host='0.0.0.0', reload = True)
```

`templates/dash.html`

```js
<html>
   <head>
      <title>my random graph</title>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      <script src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script> 
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <div id = "container" style = "width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
      <script language = "JavaScript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            var title = {
               text: "{{ title }}"
            };
            var credits = {
                  enabled: false
            };
            var subtitle = {
               text: 'test'
            };
            var xAxis = {
               categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                  'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            };
            var yAxis = {
               title: {
                  text: 'Temperature (\xB0C)'
               },
               plotLines: [{
                  value: 0,
                  width: 1,
                  color: '#808080'
               }]
            };   

            var tooltip = {
               valueSuffix: '\xB0C'
            }
            var legend = {
               layout: 'vertical',
               align: 'right',
               verticalAlign: 'middle',
               borderWidth: 0
            };
            var series =  [{
                  name: 'Tokyo',
                  data: {{ tokyo_data }}
               }, 
               {
                  name: 'New York',
                  data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 
                     24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
               }, 
               {
                  name: 'Berlin',
                  data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6,
                     17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
               }, 
               {
                  name: 'London',
                  data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 
                     16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
               }
            ];

            var json = {};
            json.title = title;
            json.subtitle = subtitle;
            json.xAxis = xAxis;
            json.yAxis = yAxis;
            json.tooltip = tooltip;
            json.legend = legend;
            json.series = series;
            json.credits = credits;

            $('#container').highcharts(json);
         });
      </script>
   </body>
   
</html>
```

So far, it's working fine and showing the plot. Each time I refresh the page, I get a new random plot for Tokyo.

[image: plot]

But I want to make the plot update itself (hopefully, without refreshing the full page) once the database is updated. How can I update the plot from fastapi end without page refresh?

Comment: You must use either `websockets` or a javascript loop on the client that continuously fetches data from a `REST API`. Either way, you then update on the client side the graph

Comment: To redraw only chart you can use chart.events.redraw `https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw`

Comment: use SSE, see https://ron.sh/creating-real-time-charts-with-fastapi/